# Why does Git doesn't update in my server's folder?

Tags: git, server, commit

I made a git repo in my server's folder with a path `\\xxxxxx\Demo`, then I made a git clone and everything is ok, but when I make the commit and push it to the remote (the server's folder) it says that it was succesufully

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 212 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To //xxxxxx//Demo
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

But when I check the file in the server isn't updated so I've proceed to check the log with `git log` and it shows me the commit that I've pushed but there are no changes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you just checking to see that your changes made it to the server? They will not show up in a working directory on the bare repository on the server. They are stored in a compressed form in the .git directory.  Your can verify that the changes are there by pulling to a different local directory.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update files on the server you need to run `git pull` on the server. Pushing changes just the state of files in .git folder.

It is very common to use bare git repository on the server.

[Getting Git on Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server#_git_on_the_server)

Comment: It didn't work
`$ git pull`
`fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Answer (score 1):

You've configured a `bare repository` on server side.
You can't run `git pull` without a working tree, but you could only run `git fetch`.

Bare repositories are intended to track all VCS changes but you can't use them as a git working copy with resources. You could try to create another repository on server side (not bare) and pull resources from bare repository.